# Undefined reference for boost::mutex in struct

Tags: c++, boost-mutex

I want to use a boost::mutex for the function *add* of my struct *Cell*. Here is the definition of my struct in Detector.h

```c++
class Detector {

private:
    struct  Cell{
        static boost::mutex mutex_;
        double energy;
        double sqrt_energy;
        int histories;

        inline Cell(): energy(0.f), sqrt_energy(0.f), histories(0.f) {
            boost::mutex mutex_;  //I tried with and without this line
        };  

        inline void add(double new_energy) {
            mutex_.lock();
            energy += new_energy;
            sqrt_energy += new_energy*new_energy;
            ++histories;
            mutex_.unlock();
        };
    };

    typedef std::vector<Cell> CellVector;
    CellVector EnergyPrimary;

}
```

And I use my function *add* in Detector.cpp on a vector of *Cell*.

```c++
Dectetor::Detector() : {
  nVoxelX=1024;
  nVoxelY=1024;
  size=nVoxelX*nVoxelY;
  EnergyPrimary=CellVector(size);
}

void Detector::Score(int cellID, double new_energy) {
  EnergyPrimary[cellID].add(new_energy);
}
```

When I try to compile it I have a undefined reference error for mutex_.lock() and mutex_.unlock(). But why is it working before when I overload the operator += with a similar function  (and when I called EnergyPrimary[cellID].energy += new_energy;)?

```c++
inline bool operator+= (double new_energy) {
    mutex_.lock();
    energy += new_energy;
    mutex_.unlock();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Are you including the header file? Your compiler knows where to find boost?

Comment: Your 'mutex_' is static but I don't see where you define it. You really want only one mutex for all cell and all detectors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Jepessen : Yes I include it and yes my compiler finds boost. My error is undefined reference to `Detector::Cell::mutex_'

Comment: qPCR4vir : I tried to define it (I edit my post with this line), but it still doesn't work. I want one mutex per cell.

Comment: @Marie That's a linker error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `mutex_` as a static member of the class, which means it is not a per-instance member. Therefore you can't initialize in the constructor. Instead it must be initialized in a source file, in your case most likely `Detector.cpp`.

The code for the initialization should be:

```
boost::mutex Detector::Cell::mutex_;
```

If you don't want it to be a static member (you want one mutex per Cell) remove the `static` qualifier.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my static mutex to a pointer to mutex which I initialise in my inline Cell() function and it seems to work.